# Updating and deploying SSIS code

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working with Legacy code here, and I'm not too familiar with SSIS.
I'd like to update a dtsx file, but the question is, once it's been updated, do I need to do something to deploy it? Or will the server just run the new code next time it runs?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Deployed SSIS packages are typically stored in the msdb database or on the file system on the SQL Server.  Deployed packages typically aren't stored with the metadata files that you need to open the package in BIDS.  Assuming you opened the SSIS package from the saved location where the BIDS/Visual Studio project files are, yes, you'll need to re-deploy the package.  If you deploy it to the same location, it will replace the package.  *Technically* you could edit the file by hand in place since it's just an XML file, but I'm assuming you're not doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you should NEVER make a change on prod without testing on dev/QA, of course you need to deploy it.